# featherlight-last-slide not occurring

Tags: jquery, featherlight.js

I've added a gallery to my site and I want it to stop on the last slide.

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight/#featherlight-gallery) it looks like this is supposed to happen automatically?  But it's not.

In the example the second gallery is stopping on the last slide:
http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/gallery.html

it looks like the class featherlight-last-slide and featherlight-first-slide are not being applied

in the jsfiddle it's not stopping on the first or last slide either
http://jsfiddle.net/JNsu6/15/

```
<div data-featherlight-gallery data-featherlight-filter="a">
<a href="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7070/6874560581_dc2b407cc0_b.jpg"><img src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7070/6874560581_dc2b407cc0_q.jpg" /></a>
<a href="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4005/4400559493_3403152632_o.jpg"><img src="http://farm5.staticflickr.com/4005/4400559493_f652202d1b_q.jpg" /></a>
<a href="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/174/396673914_be9d1312b1_o.jpg"><img src="http://farm1.staticflickr.com/174/396673914_be9d1312b1_q.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the doc, `featherlight-first-slide` and `featherlight-last-slide` are css classes applied to the featherlight. It doesn't stop automatically or do anything else, but allows you for easy customization.

Comment: right, so how are those classes applied? I'd imagine the script should be doing it automatically, but it doesn't appear that's the case in either my site, or the jsfiddle.

Comment: Try inspecting... `$('.featherlight-first-slide')`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was actually using an older version of the plugin.  Version 1.3.4 does not have the first-slide and last-slide functionality in it.

Updating to 1.4.0 fixed the problem